# Comparing and ranking differentiating attributes across groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, cramers-v

I'm looking for some help on how to approach this problem. Say I have two or more groups of people. Each group has characteristics and attributes. For example, say we have the following two groups:

Group 1 (100 members)

- 10% own a car
- 45% have a college degree
- 80% female

Group 2 (150 members)

- 30% own a car
- 50% have a college degree
- 35% female

I'm trying to figure what test takes these three attributes and ranks them according to how differentiating they are. In this case, from an intuitive point of view, I would rank the attributes like this, starting from most differentiating at the top.

- female (since 80% is far greater than 35%)
- owns a car (since 30% is slightly greater than 10%)
- has college degree (since 45% is not very different from 50%)

I've looked into chi-squared test of significance but that test involves comparing observations to expectations. Would I just assume each group has 50/50 proportion for each attribute and run the test against that? I've considered Cramer's V as a measure of association but would like your take on how to best approach this.

Comment: This is a nice first question! Note that there's no need to add a "thanks" at the end of your post - in fact we prefer that you don't (we try to keep things "to the point" so it is easier for readers to find the information we need), but you can thank whichever answer helps you the most by "accepting" it (green tick).